# How do you create a Text watermark on a Image

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, minimagick

How to create a Text watermark on a image using minimagick. I tried this code (http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/197-how-to-add-a-text-caption-to-an-image-with-minimagick-and-ruby) but it doesnt work for me.